# .NET Standard library sets the target preprocessor to NETSTANDARD2_0 when the calling assembly is .NET framework 4.7.2?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I've created three projects: 2 console applications targeting .NET Core 2.1 and .NET Framework 4.7.2 respectively, and a .NET Standard library (targeting both .NET standard 2.0 and .NET core 2.1 by specifying the required TFMs in the `TargetFrameworks` tag of the .csproj file):

Here is the only class in the .NET Standard library:

```
public class StdClass
    {
        public string GetCallingPlatform()
        {
#if NETCOREAPP2_1
            return "Core2.1";
#elif NETCOREAPP2_0
            return "Core2.0";

#elif NETSTANDARD2_0
            return "Standard2.0";
#elif NET472
            return "NetFramework4.7.2";
#else
            return "NotSpecified";
#endif
        }

    }
```

Then, I added a reference to this library from the two console applications and in the `Main` method of both, I called the `GetCallingPlatform`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StdClass stdClass = new StdClass();
        var platform = stdClass.GetCallingPlatform();
        Console.WriteLine(platform);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The .NET Core 2.1 console app hits the `NETCOREAPP2_1` preprocessor as expected, but the .NET framework console app hits the `NETSTANDARD2_0` preprocessor, I was expecting to hit either `NET472` or the `#else` block since the TFM `net472` not specified in the TargetFrameworks

Comment: Thanks, now less confusing, but according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support the .NET standard 2.0 supports up to .NET framework 4.6.1

Comment: It says it supports 4.6.1 and above. "The following table lists the minimum platform versions that support each .NET Standard version."

Comment: .NET 4.7.2 is superset of 4.6.1 which means that .NET Standard 2.0 supports major part of .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: Please explain more properly what you expect to happen and why.

Comment: You should add the NuGet package also to use entry project, so that the `net472` copy overwrites the `netstandard2.0` copy.

Comment: @LexLi Which NuGet package?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. You need to add `net472` to target frameworks so that the conditional compilation would work as you wished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shared class library will be compiled for all declared target frameworks, each in their own directory under `bin\Debug`, so `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1` and `bin\Debug\netstandard2.0`.

When compiling those versions targeting those frameworks, the compiler directive will be applied. The .NET Standard version will return "Standard2.0" and the .NET Core verison will return "Core2.1".

After this library has been compiled, your console applications will be compiled. Your .NET Core application will reference the .NET Core version of the library (and hence print "Core2.1"), and the .NET Framework 4.7.2 version, which can reference .NET Standard libraries, will print "Standard2.0" - because that's been baked into that version of the library.